# MOSFET's delay of off falling time

Tags: mosfet

I made the circuit using MOSFET.
The falling time when MOSFET is off is too long.
I use the resister 200kohm for test load.
HA17555 output max. current is 200mA and output voltage waveform looked complete squre.

Is it because I use too big resister(200kohm)?

---

It's my circuit and waveforms.
Falling time is too slow. Is it because of high reaistor load.
[image: circuit and waveform]

Comment: Yes. Why 200k? You could easily try 2k or 200 Ohms.

Comment: How long does it take to decay? Milliseconds? Microseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MOSFET driving circuit appears to be OK but light on Vgs voltage. If the MOSFET is properly driven it should be turning on (low) rapidly assuming your control signal does the same. Your waveform does not appear correct. You show a slow turn on (Turn Off is your term), this is driven by the FET’s drain, The turn on (high) should have the ramp or RC curve. The only other possibility is the Vgs threshold is 4V max indicating you are under driving the MOSFET. Try raising the 5V to 6V or 7V and see if the problem goes away. You are also using a TO3 case which has more capacity then the smaller packages.

Comment: Thanks for kind explaination. I think it is becasue i put too high dummy resistor. If i insert 10kohm, It was OK. I think it is because FET's capacitance and speed of resistance variation. Thanks.